# Objective-C release, autorelease, clarification needed

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I am pretty sure this is correct, but if possible could you confirm

```
[[self doublyLinkedList] add:[n1 autorelease]];
```

and

```
[[self doublyLinkedList] add:n1];
[n1 release];
```

will both produce the same `retainCount` for the n1, once the pool is drained

Comment: Both options will be correct or incorrect depending on whether you own `n1` or not. You own `n1` if you created or retained it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, result will be the same in both cases.

Comment: Thanks man! I also could have `return [self atorelease]` from n1's class right?

Comment: It would be a bad practice. Objects should not to call `retain` and `release` (`autorelease`) on them selfs.

Comment: @aleksejs answer is correct, the comment is not.  Methods that return objects should generally return autoreleased objects.  Either a factory method will return `[instance autorelease]` or an instance method may often do `return [[self retain] autorelease];'

Comment: Let's say more specific. An object shouldn't do anything may affect its `retainCount` – `return [[self retain] autorelease];` won't affect `retainCount` in general.

Answer (score 3):

Although both methods will eventually result in the same retain count, explicitly calling release will be more efficient because the object will not have to be added to and removed from the auto-release pool.